# How can I recover my phone screen after testing foldable emulator?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-10.0, foldable-devices

Android Q(10) is coming. So, I am corresponding to the OS.

So, I downloaded `FoldableEmulator.apk` [here in the Samsung Developer website](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/foldable/test).

After installing & granting the two permissions in the document, I opened the app on my device and a pop up comes up. Then, my device screen has been broken. It moved down vertically like 2-3cm. I uninstalled the `FoldableEmulator` by `adb uninstall com.samsung.android.foldable.emulator`. And then restarted the phone(The Power off, Restart, Emergency mode off button are shown after pressing the Power Button. However, they don't work at all).

[image]

I also clicked this `exit button` before the uninstallation but nothing worked.

What can I try? I don't really want to reset my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the UI doesn't interact correctly(correct x, y position when I touch the screen), the bubble button worked when I touch a bit higher area.

However, the screen became more weird. So, I decided to format my phone.

First thing that I did was,

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

for double check.

And ta-da. The screen came back.

references:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/175885/how-to-factory-reset-android-using-adb/175888